# Pgrouting PHP don't work with Openlayers and GeoExt

Tags: openlayers, pgrouting, geoext, php

I'm working with this [source code](https://github.com/pgRouting/workshop/releases/tag/v0.6.1). Html file (Openlayers + GeoExt) seems to work fine - everything shows up correctly but when I click on map nothing happend. I use my OSM data loaded to postregsql by osm2po. I think the problem is PHP file. I have changed it by myself but I'm almost sure I have made some mistake. Maybe somebody can help me to figured out what's wrong? Maybe the sql queries did errors? Any sugestions? I use PostgreSQL 9.5.3, PostGIS 2.2 and pgRouting 2.3.2. I'm not sure if my software version is comaptibile with used tutorial

PHP file:

```
<? php
```

```
// Database connection settings
   define("PG_DB", "ble");
  define("PG_HOST", "localhost"); 
  define("PG_USER", "postgres");
  define("PG_PSSWD", "db_pass");
  define("PG_PORT", "5432"); 
  define("TABLE",   "aa_2po_4pgr");
```

// Retrieve start point
   $start = split(' ',$_REQUEST['startpoint']);
   $startPoint = array($start[0], $start[1](https://github.com/pgRouting/workshop/releases/tag/v0.6.1));

// Retrieve end point
   $end = split(' ',$_REQUEST['finalpoint']);
   $endPoint = array($end[0], $end[1](https://github.com/pgRouting/workshop/releases/tag/v0.6.1));

?>

// Find the nearest edge
   $startEdge = findNearestEdge($startPoint);
   $endEdge   = findNearestEdge($endPoint);

   // FUNCTION findNearestEdge
   function findNearestEdge($lonlat) {

      // Connect to database
      $con = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." port=".PG_PORT." user=".PG_USER."    password=".PG_PSSWD)
    or die("nie udalo sie polaczyc z baza danych");

      $sql = "SELECT id, source, target, geom_way, 
                  ST_distance(geom_way, ST_GeometryFromText(
                       'POINT(".$lonlat[0]." ".$lonlat[1].")', 4326)) AS dist 
                 FROM ".TABLE."  
                 WHERE geom_way(
                       '(".($lonlat[0]-0.1)." 
                              ".($lonlat[1]-0.1).", 
                              ".($lonlat[0]+0.1)." 
                              ".($lonlat[1]+0.1).")') 
                 ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1";

      $query = pg_query($con,$sql);  

      $edge['id']      = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0);  
      $edge['source']   = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 1);  
      $edge['target']   = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 2);  
      $edge['geom_way'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 3);  

      // Close database connection
      pg_close($con);

      return $edge;
   }

?>

```
// Select the routing algorithm
   switch($_REQUEST['method']) {

  case 'SPD' : // Shortest Path Dijkstra 

    $sql = "SELECT rt.id, ST_AsGeoJSON(rt.geom_way) AS geojson, 
                 length(rt.geom_way) AS length, ".TABLE.".id 
              FROM ".TABLE.", 
                  (SELECT id, geom_way 
                      FROM pgr_dijkstra(
                          '".TABLE."',
                          ".$startEdge['source'].",
                          ".$endEdge['target'].",
                          0.1)
                   ) as rt 
              WHERE ".TABLE.".id=rt.gid;";
    break;
```

} // close switch

// Connect to database
   $dbcon = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." port=".PG_PORT." user=".PG_USER."    password=".PG_PSSWD);

// Perform database query
   $query = pg_query($dbcon,$sql);

?>

'FeatureCollection',
      'features'  => array()
   ); 

   // Add edges to GeoJSON array
   while($edge=pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {  

      $feature = array(
         'type' => 'Feature',
         'geometry' => json_decode($edge['geojson'], true),
         'crs' => array(
            'type' => 'EPSG',
            'properties' => array('code' => '4326')
         ),
         'properties' => array(
            'id' => $edge['id'],
            'length' => $edge['length']
         )
      );

      // Add feature array to feature collection array
      array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
   }


   // Close database connection
   pg_close($dbcon);

   // Return routing result
   header('Content-type: application/json',true);
   echo json_encode($geojson);

?>

After I lunch it in localhost (xampp) in browser i got this:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: startpoint in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **12**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **13**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: finalpoint in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **16**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **17**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  function geom_way(unknown) doesn't exist
>   LINE 5:               WHERE geom_way(
>                               ^
>   HINT:  No function more matching to the given name and types of arguments. Perhaps you should add explicit projection types. in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **45**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **47**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **48**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **49**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **50**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  function geom_way(unknown) doesn't exist
>   LINE 5:               WHERE geom_way(
>                               ^
>   HINT:  No function more matching to the given name and types of arguments. Perhaps you should add explicit projection types. in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **45**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **47**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **48**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **49**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **50**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: method in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **63**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined variable: sql in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **86**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_query(): Query failed:  in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **86**
>   
>   **Warning**:  pg_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp2\htdocs\pgrout\php\pgrouting.php** on line **99**
>   {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[]}

Comment: You have looked at the publishing date of release, don't you? The current pgRouting release will not work with the old workshop anymore, and there will be many changes necessary to make it work. You had to use a pgRouting version of 2011.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Just like I thought - one thing is the correct PHP queries, other thing is the pgRouting version. But do you know which version of pgRouting will work with this workshop? And is it still able to download it? If yes, do I have to change the Postgresql version to older one too?

Comment: I think this workshop was using pgRouting 1.x and also a very early version of OpenLayers. It will be a lot of effort to make it work. I do not recommend you this.

Comment: Sad to hear but it's true. I know that the latest workshop shows how to implement pgRouting on Geoserver and then to the Openlayers by WMS. But to show it online I need to buy special hosting that works with Geoserver, for example [AcuGIS](https://www.acugis.com/geoserver-hosting.htm). But it's not the best resolution for me. I hope to doing that by PHP queries. The problem is I can't find good tutorial with 2.x pgrouting version and PHP script. Any ideas where to find good tutorial?

Comment: You don't have to have a different hosting plan. But you have to learn how to make a PostgreSQL query through your programming language of choice. You won't get very far otherwise.